# How to add second elements of a tuple whose first elements meet a condition?

Tags: python-3.x, list, numpy, sum, tuples

I have a large list of tuples:

```
A = [(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 5), ..., (11, 3), (23, 1), (29, 0)]
```

Now, I want to add up those second elements whose first element is in the specific range, *[3, 11]* which should yield 5+...+3.

Here is my solution:

```
xs, ys = [i[0] for i in A], [i[1] for i in A]
my_sum = 0
for i, j in zip(xs, ys):
    if 3<=i[0]<=11:
        my_sum += j
```

However, I need a shorter snippet than this if possible.

Answer (score 2):

`print(sum([i[1] for i in A if 3 <= i[0] <= 11]))`

it's a one liner :)

hope it helps

Comment: Thank You! it is shorter than what I just added to the question :)